# twitter-api: user token raises java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: twitter, clojure, slf4j, leiningen, numberformatexception

project.clj

```
(defproject twit-api-learn "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.2.2"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.2.2"]
                 [clj-http "0.9.2"]
                 [twitter-api "0.7.5"]])
```

core.clj

```
(ns twit-api-learn.core
 (:use
   [twitter.oauth]
   [twitter.callbacks]
   [twitter.callbacks.handlers]
   [twitter.api.restful])
  (:import
   (twitter.callbacks.protocols SyncSingleCallback)))

(def my-creds (make-oauth-creds 0123456
                                0123456
                                012345-012345
                                0123456))
```

Error:

```
user=> (require 'twit-api-learn.core)
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

CompilerException java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number: 012345-012345, compiling:(twit_api_learn/core.clj:10:160)
```

So the error is being raised on the user token - the (fake) number 012345-012345. All of the "012345"s actually have their correct counterpart in core.clj.

Did I mention I'm new? :)

Comment: `012345-012345` is indeed not a number. I don't see from the source of `twitter-api` what type that arg should have, but have you tried making each of those a string? ie. "012345-012345", "0123456" ...

Comment: I have not. I shall try making them strings now.

Comment: @noisesmith: Worked! Resubmit it as an answer so I can mark you as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`012345-012345` is indeed not a number, but the Clojure reader would try to treat it as one (before failing).

I don't see from the source of `twitter-api` what type that arg should have, but try making each argument a String, ie. "012345-012345", "0123456" ...

Comment: Thanks. Also, if doing something such as "(users-show :oauth-creds my-creds :params {:screen-name "AdamJWynne"})" in the REPL, do I have to, line by line, (require) each of the [twitter.xxxx] in the namespace?

Comment: you can also switch to an ns from a file that you load `(require 'my.ns)` then `(in-ns 'my.ns)`, and as long as you are in that ns you can access all the bindings visible from that ns via its require or use statements.

Comment: Wow. You rock! Is that a pretty normal repl command? I searched all around and obviously seached in the wrong place. This is my first time interacting with a foreign API...soo pumped. I just for the first time called information from Twitter! I am so excited.

Comment: To clarify, there are no "commands" in clojure, and with very few exceptions anything you can do in a source file you can do in the repl and visa versa. It is helpful to be familiar with the clojure.core [cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet)